# makefile prerequisites rebuild failed when using .d-dependencies-file

Tags: c, makefile

As pleased i recreated this Question to give my actual example:

My Problem is, when `httpd-fsdata-erw.h` is missing at the very first build the rule `httpd-fsdata-erw.h::` creates it for me and erverything works fine.

If i touch `httpd-fsdata-erw.h` make recognised it and is building `sourcefile1.o`, `sourcefile2.o` and everything else neede again. Wonderful!

But when i delete `httpd-fsdata-erw.h` it. Make is checking the prerequisites  and does nothing because it said **"nothing to be done"** although `httpd-fsdata-erw.h` is missing.

Now when i touch `sourcefile2.h` make can't find a rule to make target `httpd-fsdata-erw.h`.

**MAYBE i mixed up some error-messages**

I can fix it with the `.PONY:`-target, but as you know every turn it will rebuild most of the stuff.

File-Overview:

```
extension
|
|-- Makefile
|--(httpd-fsdata-erw.h) (created by perl
|--(httpd-fsdata-erw.c) (created by perl)
|--(httpd-fsdata-erw.o)
|-- ext.o
|-- ext.bin


TOPDIR-- Makefile
|-- obj_dir
|   |--sourcefile1.o
|   |--sourcefile1.d
|   |--sourcefile2.o
|   |--sourcefile2.d
|   |--...
|
|-- app
|   |
|   |--sourcefile1.c (needs httpd-fsdata-erw.h)
|   |--sourcefile2.c 
|   |--sourcefile2.h (needs httpd-fsdata-erw.h)
|   |--sourcefile3.c 
|   |--sourcefile4.c 
|   |
|   |--appskt
|   |  |--webserver
|   |  |  |-- Makefile
|   |  |  |...
|   |  |  |--fsdata
|   |  |     |--index.html
|   |  |     |--somejavascript.js
|   |  |
|   |  |
|   |  |--shell
|   |  |  |...
|   |  |--crypto
|   |  |  |...
|   |  |--ftp
|   |  |  |...
|   |  |
|
|
|-- contiki
|   |--Makefile.include
|   
|   
|   
|-- plattform
|   |-- cpu
|   |  |-- Makefile.r7s7210
|   |  |
|   |  |
```

The Makefile in directory=webserver creates with a perl-script httpd-fsdata-erw.h .c and .o to the extension-folder with the rule

```
HTTPD_FSDATA_ERW_FILES=httpd-fsdata-erw.c httpd-fsdata-erw.h
$(HTTPD_FSDATA_ERW_FILES): $(PATH_WEBSERVER)/index.html $(PATH_WEBSERVER)/somejavascript.js
    perl makefsdata -d $(HT.... 

web_content: $(HTTPD_FSDATA_ERW_FILES)
```

TOPDIR-- Makefile:

```
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include

all: project.bin

project.bin: $(somestuff1) $(somestuff2) $(TARGET_PATH)/$(CONTIKI_PROJECT).$(TARGET)
  @cmd .... nothing important, just a windows batch-file
```

|-- contiki--Makefile.include:

```
-include $(PATH_...)/Makefile.r7s7210

-include ${addprefix $(OBJECTDIR)/,$(CONTIKI_SOURCEFILES:.c=.d) \
                                   $(PROJECT_SOURCEFILES:.c=.d)}    

#.PHONY: httpd-fsdata-erw.h
httpd-fsdata-erw.h::
    @$(MAKE) -j1 $(EXT_BIN) -C $(EXT_PATH) -f Makefile

$(TARGET_PATH)/%.$(TARGET): %.co $(PROJECT_OBJECTFILES) $(PROJECT_LIBRARIES) contiki-$(TARGET).a
  some linking stuff
```

|-- plattform -- cpu -- Makefile.r7s7210:

```
$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJECTDIR):
  ...
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(IAR_INCLUDES) ... $< --dependencies=n $(@:.o=.d) -o $@)
```

Comment: You should include the content of `myfile.d`, and how it is generated. Also, what is the purpose of your first rule for `missing.h` ?

Comment: The rule is only to prof that there is an dependency.

Comment: I include the content with `-include myfile1.d`

Comment: The `make[1]:...` indicates the use of recursive Make, which is strange. And `$(warning showMeThis)` is Make syntax; if you did not precede it with a TAB, Make will display this warning whether or not it executes the rule, and if you *did* precede it with a tab, the shell will evaluate it and display nothing. Something is fishy here; either you are not showing us the real code, or you are not paying attention to the real output, or... I think you should show us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I have a very huge contiki-Project with about 300 C-files. I tried to create a simple example. This is why i used replacements like **missing.h** and **myfile1**. The master-Makefile includes Makefiles and also executes some other makefiles. It's very tricky.

Comment: So copy the whole system to a private sandbox where you can whittle it down to a minimal complete example. If you can't do that, then your build system is unmaintainable.

Comment: I doubt that make says `*** No rule to make target: missing.h` as long as you have the rule `missing.h: showMeThis`. What I don't understand is why you have `showMeThis` as dependency there. Rather it should complain that it doesn't know how to make `showMeThis`

Comment: @Chris: You seem to be attempting to automatically discover dependencies on a generated header file. This won't work since the dependency output is emitted as a by-product during compilation and so once the requirement is discovered the build has already failed. To be honest I don't know of any clean ways of dealing with this in make. The workarounds I have seen is to partition the build into discrete code-generation or dependency-discovery phases, which works well enough so long as you don't go Rube-Goldberg with code generators dynamically dependent on other code generators.

Answer (score 0):

> But when i delete the "missing.h"-file after the very first build, make is unable to find a target.
>
> Is this because of the structure of the .d-file?

It is.

To fix that, use [`-MP` gcc command line switch](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-MP) when generating the `.d` file:

> `-MP` This option instructs CPP to add a phony target for each dependency
>          other than the main file, causing each to depend on nothing.  These
>          dummy rules work around errors make gives if you remove header
>          files without updating the Makefile to match. This is typical output:
>
> ```
>            test.o: test.c test.h
>            test.h:
> ```

Comment: I am using **iar-compiler** with the dependency option `--dependencies=n $(@:.o=.d)` which created me these .d-Files. I can't see much difference between my d.-File and your example except of **test.h**. And isn'T **test.h** a real target not a PHONY-target?

Comment: @Chris That example is from gcc documentation. `test.h` is a non-phony target. Not sure what `iar-compiler` is.